# How to trigger a workflow as specific user instead of Dependabot

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot

I have automatic PRs made by Dependabot, and a workflow which tests the code and builds everything. Workflows that are triggered by Dependabot are not able to access GitHub repo custom secrets (by design), so to make my workflow pass I need to manually commit an empty commit to the PR to be the user who triggers the workflow so the secrets will be accessible to it.

Is there more "correct" workaround for that? For example, is there some GitHub action that can trigger a workflow as specific user?

I don't want to make the secrets accessible to Dependabot, I want to make the Dependabot PRs to be executed as my user.